# Logout button not working

Tags: laravel, logout

for some reason my logout button suddenly stopped working after doing some coding, I try to revert it back to original but it still doesn't work, can anyone help me. I had checked online and some people say it might be the auth controller but I didn't touch until it

app.blade.php (so sorry for the mess)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Route:

```
Auth::routes();
//show data
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@getData')->name('home');
Route::get('user/show/{id}','HomeController@getInfo')->name("user.show");
```

HomeController:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        return view('home');
    }
```

Comment: does it reload when you click the logout button?

Comment: I just couldn't log out, I can see my name but when I click it, they didn't show anything, do you need to see the route and controller?

Comment: yes please show me

Comment: Added in the things related to authentication, but I didn't really touch anything, so could it be a bug?

Comment: is the logout button visible and clickable?

Comment: Nope, not visible

Comment: Fix this: `Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@getData')->name('home');`

Comment: @Tpojika but those route are fine

Comment: Sounds like a javascript error, did you rebuild your app.js file in any way, or update bootstrap? as l5.5 uses bootstrap and the bootstrap js to make the dropdown work. Try rebuilding your app.js file and see if you get any errors, or just make sure that your bootstrap and js is loaded properly

Comment: @Eamon so sorry for the late reply, I check  with the chrome developer tool and it show that it was the app.js file error but when I try to replace the file with the original and check it again the error still remains

Answer (score 0):

```
   <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                    @else
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                        onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        Logout
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endif
```

Seems like you removed the if statement when checking guest user. Most likely it doesn't work because use is not logged in.

Comment: tks for replying so I just have to replace guest with if ?

Comment: See above on, replace guest with if (Auth::guest()) and replace endguest with endif

Comment: I just tried replacing and they gave me "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' " but I didn't even put any ":"

Comment: Still doesn't work, it not visible when I click it but the error disappear

Comment: Parse error on which line? It should point you to the line with that error

Comment: Sorry that line is fixed after you told me it was if (Auth::guest()) but the problem still remains, the logout button can't be seen

Comment: That will be a CSS issue. You will need to use Chrome Dev Tools to figure out

Comment: Ohh I see is there anything that I need to look out for? And also there isn't any wrong with my code right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157851/discussion-between-silvanus-matiku-and-blastme).

Answer (score 0):

This may cause by javascript on your `<a>` tag before form logout not working, so a GET request to logout action was performed instead of a POST one. Replace `<a>` tag by a submit button instead.

Comment: Tks for replying, so I have to replace the dropdown-toggle with a submit button? But the problem I am facing is take there is no dropdown coming down when I try to logout, and the logout button can't be seen